# Client that uses both MQTT and MQTT-SN

Tags: client, mqtt, paho

I am wondering if there is anyway to create a client that subscribes from a broker using MQTT and publishes to another broker, through a gateway, using MQTT-SN?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create a client that would be using MQTT connection towards gateway A and MQTT-SN connection to gateway B.

Depending on code language you could use you can find IOT clients at our github account , they implement both MQTT and MQTT-SN additionally to COAP , AMQP and WS.

Currently all of them start one connection at a time , however small modification could allow 2 connections to be opened.

See [Mobius Github](https://github.com/mobius-software-ltd) for more details

BR

[Mobius Software](https://www.mobius-software.com)